# Ontology Design Using Proege

Tags: ontology, protege

Let's say we want to make an ontology model for the Light Switches in the home.Each Light Switch has two properties hasID, and hasLocation.
which way is the most correct way to doing it.

- making a class LightSwitch
- a data property hasID
- an object property hasLocation
- some individual Like LightSwitch-01, LightSwitch-02

OR

- making a class LightSwitch
- subclasses KitchenLightSwitch, LivingroomLightSwitch, and etc.
- a data property hasID
- an object property hasLocation
- some individual Like LightSwitch-01, LightSwitch-02

Answer (score 0):

In ontology design there is no right or wrong in general (of course there are situations where someone makes mistakes in the design process).

There is no such thing like "this is the one and only solution". There are always different solutions, based on your scenario, experience and what you would like to do with the ontology.

In your case you could solve your problem with both approaches (I would prefer the second one, since I'm a fan of classes). The only difference in your example that I see is that in the first one all lightswitch instances are of the type "LightSwitch" and in the second one the instances are  of theire location type (e.g. KitchenLightSwitch).

However if you are using the object property "hasLocation" you do not really need subclasses for "LightSwitch".

Create a class "Lightswitch" with the instances "Switch1, Switch2,..." and create a class Room with instances (Kitchen, Livingroom, etc).
In the last step you associate a relationship: Switch1 hasLocation Kitchen.

Another possibility would be to create the class Room and subclasses LivingRoom, KitchenRoom, etc. Each of the subclasses would have an instance "kitchenroom, livingroom, etc."

But really, its up to you. I see nothing wrong with both of your solutions. However, if you would provide more information or your context would be more complex.. maybe then one could prefer either solution A or solution B, but for exactly this example that you are asking for, both solutions are right.